# Find how many times a certain DNA base sequence occurs in a file

Tags: text-processing, scripting, bioinformatics

The assignment is to write a bash script named “countmatches” that will display the number of times a certain sequence, such as `aac`, appears in a specified file. The script should expect at least two arguments in which the first argument has to be the pathname of a file containing a valid DNA string which we are given. The remaining argument(s) are strings containing only the bases `a`, `c`, `g`, and `t` in any order. 
For each valid argument string, it will search the DNA string in the file and count how many non-overlapping occurrences of that argument string are in the DNA string (i.e., the file).

An example sequence and output would be if the string `aaccgtttgtaaccggaac` is in a file named `dnafile`, then the script should work as follows

```
$ countmatches dnafile ttt
ttt 1
```

with the command being `countmatches dnafile ttt` and the output being `ttt 1`, showing that `ttt` appears once.

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for /data/biocs/b/student.accounts/cs132/data/dna_textfiles
do
        count=$grep -o '[acgt][acgt][acgt]' /data/biocs/b/student.accounts/cs132/data/dna_textfiles | wc -w
        echo {$/data/biocs/b/student.accounts/cs132/data/dna_textfiles} ${count}
done
```

and this is the error I get

```
[Osama.Chaudry07@cslab5 assignment3]$ ./countmatches /data/biocs/b/student.accounts/cs132/data/dna_textfiles aac
./countmatches: line 6: '/data/biocs/b/student.accounts/cs132/data/dna_textfiles': not a valid identifier
```

Comment: We're not a script-writing service, but people where will be happy to help you when you hit specific issues with a script you've written.

Comment: dna_textfiles is a file with nothing but a sequence of letters a, c , g, and t. This is the file for which we have to write a script that will show you how many times a certain sequence such as aac comes up.

Comment: @Goro yes that is what the goal is, to enter any sequence that is present in the large dna_textfiles and have the output be how many times that base appears. I wrote a script for it but it isn't achieving what I want it to and I don't understand where I went wrong.

Comment: @Goro all of the repeats in a sequence. For example in the sequence aaccgtttgtaaccggaac, if I were to input the base aac, it would show that it comes up 3 times.

Comment: @Goro I have added an example of a particular sequence in a certain file in which you look for the base ttt and the output shows that in that file, the sequence contains one appearance of ttt.

Comment: @Chaudry Osama, bellow are two ideas that can do what you want, please let me know if you need further help and I can tweak it for you!

Comment: Why are you doing sequence matching using `grep` and not `blast` or `exonerate` or some similar bioinformatics tool?

Answer (score 4):

```
cat dna_textfile 
aaccgtttgtaaccggaac 

#!/bin/bash    
dna_file=/path/to/dna_textfiles
printf "\e[31mNucleotide sequence?:";
read -en 3 userInput
while [[ -z "${userInput}" ]]
do
read -en 3 userInput
done

count=$(grep -o "${userInput}" "${dna_file}" | wc -l)

echo "${userInput}", ${count}
```

output:

```
 ttt, 1
```

---

```
#!/bin/bash
#set first and second arguments (dnafile and base respectively)

dir=$1
base=$2

count=$(grep -o ${base} ${dir} | wc -l)

echo "${base}", "${count}"
```

output:

```
$ ./countmatches dnafile ttt
ttt, 1
```

---

Answer to a comment made by @Kusalananda

The solutions above counts for *non-overlapping* occurrences within a string. For example: in the string "acacaca", there are two "aca" non-overlapping occurrences, and three "aca" overlapping occurrences. In order to count *overlapping* occurrences:

```
#!/bin/bash
#set first and second arguments (sequence and base respectively)  
sequence=$1
base=$2
diff_sequence_base=$((${#sequence} - ${#base} | bc))

for ((i=0; i <= ${diff_sequence_base}; i++)); do
       [ ${sequence:i:${#base}} = $base ] && ((count++))

done
echo $base, $count


$ ./countmatches acacaca aca
aca, 3


$ ./countmatches aaccgtttttaaccggaac ttt
ttt, 3
```

Comment: Consider that sequences may overlap, as the three instances of `aca` in `acacaca`.

Comment: The user did ask: "count how many non-overlapping occurrences of that argument string are in the DNA string". So, grep is fine as coded. There are only **two** non-overlaping 'aca' in `acacaca` @Kusalananda

Comment: @Isaac Well, the user should really remove the "bioinformatics" tag if they are trying to do analysis of DNA sequences using `grep`. This _really_ should be done with some variation of the Smith-Waterman algorithm.

Comment: @Kusalananda: In the OP’s defense, they never applied the [bioinformatics] tag; Jeff Schaller added it.  But also, from a reality-check perspective, the fact that U&L *has* a [bioinformatics] tag (with over 100 questions) suggests that the community believes that processing gene text with Unix text tools is appropriate and on-topic.   (By contrast, we are not nearly so receptive to requests to parse JSON and XML without appropriate, specialized tools.)

Comment: @G-Man Processing of bioinformatics _text_ by Unix tools is perfectly OK.  Doing sequence matching of DNA with `grep` is not "bioinformatics" though. It's simply not the correct tool for the job.

Answer (score 3):

It is easy to match a `ttt` sequence and report the count of matches:

```
$ echo 'aaccgtttgtaaccggaac' | grep -o 'ttt' | wc -l
```

Or, if the sequence in in a file:

```
$ echo 'aaccgtttgtaaccggaac'>dnafile
$ grep -o 'ttt' dnafile | wc -l
1

$ grep -o 'aac' dnafile | wc -l
3
```

So, all you need to do is to code this idea in a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
dnafile=${1-./dnafile}                   # Name of the file to read (arg 1)
shift                                    # Erase arg 1.

for pat; do                              # Process all the other line arguments.
    printf '%s ' "$pat"                  # Print the patern used.
    grep -o "$pat" "$dnafile" | wc -l    # Find the count of matches.
done                                     # done.
```

Call the script (after making it excutable `chmod u+x countmatches`) like this:

```
$ ./countmatches dnafile ttt aac ccgtttg ag
ttt 1
aac 3
ccgtttg 1
ag 0
```

Answer (score 0):

For non-overlapping bases in lines in a file like

```
aaccgtttgtaaccggaac 
acacaca
```

, try

```
awk '{print gsub (base, "&")}' base="ttt" file
1
0
```

For overlapping ones, try

```
awk '{while (0 < T=index ($0, base)) {CNT++; $0 = substr($0, T+1)}; print CNT+0;  T = CNT = 0}' base="aca" file
0
3
```

In case you need the count per file in lieu of per line, sum up the `CNT`s and print out in the `END` section.